# Having trouble removing duplicate timestamps with Notepad++ regex

Tags: notepad++, regex

Recently I have been trying to edit a Discord chat log. I have it exported into raw text but I would like to clean it up. My first order of business is removing duplicate timestamps for messages that occur during the same minute from the same user. Here's an example:

```
[15-Mar-19 02:03 PM] Originalposter#1234
Hey buddy, you doing well recently?

[15-Mar-19 02:03 PM] friendlyguy#4321
yeh

[15-Mar-19 02:03 PM] friendlyguy#4321
hru
```

I would like this text to become:

```
[15-Mar-19 02:03 PM] Originalposter#1234
Hey buddy, you doing well recently?

[15-Mar-19 02:03 PM] friendlyguy#4321
yeh
hru
```

I have experimented and gotten around to find this:

```
\[(.*)\] friendlyguy#4321$(.*)$(.*)$\[(.*)\]
```

however, it doesn't find the text at all.

I believe the ($) symbols are not working correctly, but I have very little reason to believe so.

I would appreciate any help that can get me closer to figuring out how to clean up this chatlog. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\[.+?\]\h+\w+#\d+\R)[\s\S]+?\R\K\R\1(?=[\s\S]+?\R*)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(               # start group 1
  \[            # opening square bracket
  .+?           # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  \]            # closing square bracket
  \h+           # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  \w+           # 1 or more word characters
  #             # # literally
  \d+           # 1 or more digits
  \R            # any kind of linebreak
)               # end group 1
[\s\S]+?        # 1 or more any character, not greedy
\R              # any kind of linebreak
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
\R              # any kind of linebreak
\1              # backreference to group 1, same date, same user
(?=             # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
  [\s\S]+?        # 1 or more any character, not greedy
  \R*             # 0 or more linebreak
)               # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked very well. Also thanks to the others who helped, I'm very grateful :)

Comment: @user1143815: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

set Notepad to use UNIX-newline format (LF) and then use the following RegEx:

```
(\[.{18}\] \w+#\d+\s)((\S| )+\s)\s(\1)((\S| )+)
```

For replace use:

```
\1\2\5
```

Here some related links:

- https://regex101.com/r/PJ9vso/1
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBIo0.png

Regards

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
I tried putting it into Notepad++, but it said it still couldn't find it. Not sure what I am doing wrong. https://imgur.com/a/NBS8wKJ

Comment: Have you set `Edit -> EOL Conversion` to `Unix (LF)` in Notepad++?